# Prove or disprove the conjecture about the function below.

Tags: calculus, optimization, nonlinear-optimization, applications

After thousands of numerical tests we stated the conjecture that their is exactly one local extremum of the function below.
$$
{\rm f}\left(w\right)
=
{1 \over 2}\sum_{i = 1}^{n}\left({1 \over 1 + {\rm e}^{-x_{i}\,w}} -y_{i}\right)^{2}
$$

where $x_{i}, y_{i} \in \left(0, 1\right)$ are constants, $w\in \mathbb{R}$.
Can you prove or disprove it?

Comment: Interestingly, this is like fitting a logistic function via least squares. My guess is that there is something on this in mathematical statistics.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way it is phrased, the conjecture is false. Consider the example
$$f(w)=1/2\left[\left(\frac{1}{1+e^{-0.1w}}-0.9\right)^2+\left(\frac{1}{1+e^{-0.9w}}-0.1\right)^2\right],$$
or [plotted](http://fooplot.com/#W3sidHlwZSI6MCwiZXEiOiIxLzIqKDEvKDErZV4oLTAuMSp4KSktMC45KV4yKzEvMiooMS8oMStlXigtMC45KngpKS0wLjEpXjIiLCJjb2xvciI6IiNFRDA1MDUifSx7InR5cGUiOjEwMDAsIndpbmRvdyI6WyItMTUwIiwiMTUwIiwiLTAuMSIsIjAuNiJdfV0-):
[image]

Clearly, there is a unique maximum and a unique minimum, i.e., there are two extrema.

Comment: Thanks for your counterexample.